# What is the difference between SSPRK3 and RK3 time discretization methods?

Tags: finite-difference, numerics, finite-volume

Here, SSPRK3 refers to third order strong stability preserving Runge-Kutta and RK3 refres to regular third order Runge-Kutta method. The meaning of the method is obvious from the name. However there is a restriction while one is choosing the time step. It is mentioned in ["Strong stability preserving high-order time discretization methods" by Gottlieb, Shu , and Tadmor.](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/S003614450036757X) Since my problem is nonliner systems of hyperbolic PDEs (partial differential equations), related part about my problem is in the section 4.1. The question is that what is the interaction between CFL condition and strong stability preserving coefficient ?

Comment: Well, it's clearly the SSP (strong stability preserving) property. There are many RK3 methods, SSPRK3 being one among this family.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth  As you mentioned the meaning of the method is obvious from the name. However there is a restriction while one is choosing the time step. It is mentioned in "Strong stability preserving high-order time discretization methods" by Gottlieb, Shu , and Tadmor. Since my problem is nonliner, related part about my problem is in the section 4.1. What is the interaction between CFL condition and strong stability preserving coefficient ? This is my real question though.

Comment: I see. Please update your original question then to reflect what exactly it is that you are asking.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth sure.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "strong stability preserving coefficient"? I couldn't find that keyword in the paper.